# Golang: Shared communication in async http server

Tags: go

Absolute beginner to golang other than writing a simple http server. I'm researching Go as a possibility for writing an async process. If you could please provide a quick sample of how this might be accomplished:

Http request 'a' comes in, an operation is started based on POST payload in this request (with some sort of unique identifier in post or url). The async process started by 'a' will respond back to same server with original unique identifier (request 'b') while request 'a' is still open. I'd like to communicate that response back to request 'a' based on request 'b' response.

Comment: I'm not asking you to code the app, I'm just falling short on whether this would be accomplished through shared memory or channels, and if through channels, how it would be done based on a unique identifier. As I understand it, a simple example should only be a about 5-10 lines?

Comment: Is this what you're asking for? Request a comes in from client to server. Then the server issues request b back to the client. Or does the client issue a second request?

Comment: Channels are an excellent way to do this. need more details before I can give more direction though.

Comment: Request a comes in from client, due to request a, server kicks off an async process offsite, the result from this async process will be returned back to the same http server (request b) but then fed back to request a. The client issues one request, the async process is returned to the second (connected by a unique id in POST or GET, doesn't really matter). I'm just unsure how I'd connect the two requests by that unique ID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is possible to do this with channels,
I would prefer a hash (map) that is protected by a mutex,
since it is easier in this case.

To give you an idea and get you going:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

type state struct {
    *sync.Mutex // inherits locking methods
    Vals map[string]string // map ids to values
}

var State = &state{&sync.Mutex{}, map[string]string{}}

func get(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    State.Lock()
    defer State.Unlock() // ensure the lock is removed after leaving the the function
    id := req.URL.Query().Get("id") // if you need other types, take a look at strconv package
    val := State.Vals[id]
    delete(State.Vals, id)
    rw.Write([]byte("got: " + val))
}

func post(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    State.Lock()
    defer State.Unlock()
    id := req.FormValue("id")
    State.Vals[id] = req.FormValue("val")
    rw.Write([]byte("go to http://localhost:8080/?id=42"))
}

var form = `<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            ID: <input name="id" value="42" /><br />
            Val: <input name="val" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>`

func formHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.Write([]byte(form))
}

// for real routing take a look at gorilla/mux package
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    switch req.Method {
    case "POST":
        post(rw, req)
    case "GET":
        if req.URL.String() == "/form" {
            formHandler(rw, req)
            return
        }
        get(rw, req)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("go to http://localhost:8080/form")
    // thats the default webserver of the net/http package, but you may
    // create custom servers as well
    err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", http.HandlerFunc(handler))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting req.PostForm undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method PostForm)

Comment: strange it worked for me (go1.1)... however I updated the source, it should work now and is a bit shorter...

Comment: @kwolfe I looked it up - they changed the field from *http.Request.Form (go1.0) to  *http.Request.FormValue (go1.1).
However the rewritten variant *http.Request.FormValue() works with both versions. I would strongly suggest you update to go 1.1.1 since the online documentation reflects that version and it's much faster.

Comment: What would be the best way to continually check for a response on the hash map without creating a race condition?

Comment: you could simply make a get and set method on the State that do the manipulation of Vals and the locking. they should then be called instead of direct manipulation and the set method may do whatever you like if new responses appear.