# Golang: Best way to read from a hashmap w/ mutex

Tags: hashmap, go, mutex

This is a continuation from here: [Golang: Shared communication in async http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890830/golang-shared-communication-in-async-http-server)

Assuming I have a hashmap w/ locking:

```
//create async hashmap for inter request communication
type state struct {
    *sync.Mutex // inherits locking methods
    AsyncResponses map[string]string // map ids to values
}
var State = &state{&sync.Mutex{}, map[string]string{}}
```

Functions that write to this will place a lock. My question is, what is the best / fastest way to have another function check for a value without blocking writes to the hashmap? I'd like to know the instant a value is present on it.

```
MyVal = State.AsyncResponses[MyId]
```

Answer (score 5):

Reading a shared map without blocking writers is the very definition of a data race. Actually, semantically it is a data race *even when the writers will be blocked during the read*! Because as soon as you finish reading the value and unblock the writers - the value may not exists in the map anymore.

Anyway, it's not very likely that proper syncing would be a bottleneck in many programs. A non-blocking lock af a {RW,}Mutex is probably in the order of < 20 nsecs even on middle powered CPUS. I suggest to postpone optimization not only after making the program correct, but also after **measuring** where the major part of time is being spent.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that the ID that I'll be reading from is set up to be only written to once, and read once, before being removed. It is a unique identifier for the call. So I should be good with a check every 100 miliseconds? How is the read treated by go if the read occurs while there is a lock?

Comment: @kwolfe: It depends on the rest of your code, but it's pretty possible  that a channel of such IDs is a much better fit for your task than a concurrently accessed map is.

Comment: I had presented an example app and I was pointed in the direction of a hashmap with mutex. I would have loved to be able to use channels but I'm not sure how it would be accomplished. Would you mid taking a look at the original post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890830/golang-shared-communication-in-async-http-server